# tengo un problema con el if, no me funciona el código en general

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, variables, switch

tengo un problema con el código en general, no tengo idea donde esta el error porque a mi punto de vista debería funcionar, el código tendría que ir de esto: un script que permita leer un numero de mes de teclado y apartir de ese mes calcula la productividad. La productividad es 100 + el factor del mes. alguien que me eche la mano, se lo agradecería mucho............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var mes, resulatdo, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5;

const resultado=100
const factor1=15
const factor2=17
const factor3=20
const factor4=21
const factor5=0

const mes = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un mes:"))

if (mes <= 13) {
  
    switch (mes) {
        case 1: 
        suma = resultado + factor1;
            document.write(suma);
            break;
    case 2: 
        suma = resultado + factor1;
            document.write(suma);
            break;
    case 3: 
         suma = resultado + factor1;
            document.write(suma);
            break;
    case 4: 
         suma = resultado + factor2;
            document.write(suma);
            break;
    case 5: 
         suma = resultado + factor2;
            document.write(suma);
        break;
    case 6: 
         suma = resultado + factor2;
            document.write(suma);
        break;
    case 7:  
        document.write(factor5);
        break;
    case 8: 
        document.write(factor5);
        break;
    case 9: 
         suma = resultado + factor3;
            document.write(suma);
        break;
    case 10: 
        suma = resultado + factor3;
            document.write(suma);
        break;
    case 11:
        suma = resultado + factor3;
            document.write(suma);
        break;
    case 12: 
         suma = resultado + factor4;
            document.write(suma);
        break;

    default: 
        document.write("mes");
    }
} 

else {
  document.write('Error en el mes')
}

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Elimina la primera línea completa del `var mes...`, estas redefiniendo las mismas variables dos veces y eso da error de sintaxis y el javascript se para.  Acostumbrate a depurar tu código mirando la consola de tu navegador pues allí seguro que sale el error, o usa herramientas online como [esta](https://jsfiddle.net/94ao8ejv/) donde, si pulsas sobre la palabra "consola", se te abrira la consola y verás el error

Comment: @masterguru, oh, escribí la respuesta al mismo tiempo que el comentario, lo siento

Comment: @HeytalePazguato No pasa nada, solo que lo veia como un error tipográfico, por eso tampoco me puse a redartarla, y la he marcado como tal para cerrarla, no se, ahora ya la has posteado, dejala, total, es una explicación ampliada que seguro que le va bien también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando defines variables y constantes no puedes utilizar el mismo nombre, una variable se asigna a una palabra clave cuyo valor puede cambiar a lo largo del programa, por ejemplo `suma`. Una constante contiene un valor que no puede cambiar, como su nombre lo dice, es constante.

El primer error es que tienes definidas variables y constantes con las mismas palabras claves

```
var mes, resulatdo, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5;

const resultado=100
const factor1=15
const factor2=17
const factor3=20
const factor4=21
const factor5=0
```

Si deseas que `resultado` y los factores sean constantes entonces no los declares como `var`

También te recomendaría inicializar `suma`

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var mes = 0;
var suma = 0;

const resultado = 100;
const factor1 = 15;
const factor2 = 17;
const factor3 = 20;
const factor4 = 21;
const factor5 = 0;

mes = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un mes:"))

if (mes <= 13) {
  
    switch (mes) {
        case 1: 
                suma = resultado + factor1;
            document.write(suma);
            break;
      case 2: 
          suma = resultado + factor1;
              document.write(suma);
              break;
      case 3: 
           suma = resultado + factor1;
              document.write(suma);
              break;
      case 4: 
           suma = resultado + factor2;
              document.write(suma);
              break;
      case 5: 
           suma = resultado + factor2;
              document.write(suma);
          break;
      case 6: 
           suma = resultado + factor2;
              document.write(suma);
          break;
      case 7:
          document.write(factor5);
          break;
      case 8: 
          document.write(factor5);
          break;
      case 9: 
           suma = resultado + factor3;
              document.write(suma);
          break;
      case 10: 
          suma = resultado + factor3;
              document.write(suma);
          break;
      case 11:
          suma = resultado + factor3;
              document.write(suma);
          break;
      case 12: 
           suma = resultado + factor4;
              document.write(suma);
          break;

    default: 
        document.write("mes");
    }
} 

else {
  document.write('Error en el mes')
}
```

**Nota;** En tu pregunta mencionas que cada mes suma el resultado mas un factor, en algunos meses tienes únicamente el factor, lo dejé así porque no se si así esperabas que funcionara

Comment: hermano te lo agradezco un montón, que Dios te bendiga :)

Answer (score 0):

El navegador web chromium al presionar f12 me mostro en la solapa de consola el error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'factor1' has already been declared
o traducido
Error de sintaxis:el identificador 'factor1' ya se ha declarado

Lo declaras como valor variable (var) aquì:

```
var mes, resulatdo, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5;
```

y aquì como constante (const)

```
const resultado=100
const factor1=15
```

El error es que lo declaraste dos veces una como var y otra como const con el mismo nombre.

Cosas a brindar atención para aprender a pescar ;)

1. Valida las herramientas de depuración de los navegadores web para
   saltar estos errores
2. Tu còdigo siempre declaralo con la palabra reservada "var" es raro
   tener la necesidad de declarar variables constantes o que no cambien
   en el proceso de ejecución de tu código.